# xml /XSD file source ssis 2010 - data at root level is invalid to SQL server table

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, xsd, etl

I am trying to learn how to load an XML (XML source) into SSIS 2010 , the data will then go to an SQL Server 2012 Table.

The issue I am having, Is I am trying to follow a tutorial, and I am getting the same error:

> The XML Source was unable to read the XML data. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

This when downloading any of the tables - the one I have chosen is region.

Here is the script - this is in an XSD file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="countries">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="country">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="iso2Code" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="region">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"       use="optional" />
                </xs:extension>
              </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="adminregion">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"     use="optional" />
                </xs:extension>
              </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="incomeLevel">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"    use="optional" />
                </xs:extension>
              </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lendingType">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"    use="optional" />
                </xs:extension>
              </xs:simpleContent>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="capitalCity" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="longitude" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="latitude" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="page" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="optional" />
  <xs:attribute name="pages" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="optional" />
  <xs:attribute name="per_page" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="optional" />
  <xs:attribute name="total" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="optional" />
</xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
     </xs:schema>
```

The trail site is http://api.worldbank.org/countries

I have tried changing the top line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

with no success. Please help

Comment: This looks like an XSD vs XML

Comment: yes sorry just edited it. the source code is in an XSD file, as this has the XML structure. please help, why it wont work. it keeps saying data at Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.error